# How to put footnote in abstract

Tags: footnotes, abstract

I can not understand why footnote is not working here

```
\documentclass[JMC]{degruyter-journal} % Journal of Mathematical Cryptology
% https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/degruyter-journal_2.cls
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape,
  morekeywords={append,to},
  escapechar=\%
}
\firstpage{1}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[OT1]{eulervm}

\newtheorem {exam}{Example}
%\newcommand{\qed}{\hfill$\blacksquare$}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5mm}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
%\pagestyle{empty}


%\font\euler=eurm10
\newcommand{\MST}{\mbox{$MST_3$}} 
\newcommand{\G}{\mbox{$\cal{G}$}}
\newcommand{\HH}{\mbox{$\cal{H}$}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mbox{$\cal{C}$}}
\newcommand{\J}{\mbox{$\cal{J}$}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mbox{$\cal{Z}$}}
\newcommand{\BB}{\mbox{$\cal B$}}
\newcommand{\M}{\mbox{$\cal M$}}
\newcommand{\CI}{\mbox{$\cal I$}}
\newcommand{\K}{\mbox{$\cal K$}}
\newcommand{\CS}{\mbox{$\cal S$}}
\newcommand{\GL}{\mbox{$\mathsf{GL}$}}

\newcommand{\GF}{\mbox{${\mathbb F}$}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mbox{${\mathbb N}$}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mbox{${\mathbb Z}$}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mbox{${\mathbb R}$}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mbox{${\cal X}$}}
%\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\parskip}{2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
%\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
%\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.75in}
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.4in}

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{4pt}

\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\breakline}{\\}
\newcommand{\algline}{\line(0,1){8}\line(1,0){65}}
\newcommand{\algorithmend}{\vspace{-4mm}\noindent\algline\\\vspace{-2mm}}
\newcommand{\algorithmendnoitem}{\par\vspace{-1mm}\noindent\algline\\}
\newcommand{\skipbeforealgorithm}{\vspace{2mm}}
\newcommand{\skipafteralgorithm}{\vspace{-1.5mm}\noindent}
\newcommand{\skipbeforesection}{\vspace{1mm}}


\doi{xxx}
\communicated{xxx}
\received{xxx}
\revised{xxx}
%
%
\title{gggg}
\headlinetitle{hhh}

\lastnameone{ L}
\firstnameone{Y}
\nameshortone{Y L}
\addressone{State }
\countryone{H }
\emailone{abc@gmail.com}

\abstract{
In this paper\footnote{footnotes working fine}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to answer your question, we need to know how `\abstract` is define or works, and that is most likely hidden inside `degruyter-journal.cls`. Where can we find the document class?

Comment: This is Journal of Mathematical Cryptology class.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Please spoon-feed your audience with a link to `degruyter-journal.cls`. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: The link is https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/degruyter-journal_2.cls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately your document fails in a similar way to the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\test{\footnote{test}}

\begin{document}

test is \ifthenelse{\equal{\test}{}}{}{not }blank.

\end{document}
```

It boils down to an [`ifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) test for for a blank argument. You need to `\protect` the `\footnote` from expanding in those cases:

```
\abstract{%
In this paper\protect\footnote{footnotes working fine}...
}
```